# How to handle server push messages and their side effects in React / Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Consider the following situation. I am implementing a chat and want to send typing indicators to the clients to let them know if a user is currently typing. These typing indicators are send to the clients via a websocket.

It is important to note that the client receiving the typing indicator is not the one who dispatched the corresponding action.

The typing indicator is received by the client and translated into an action which immediately updates the state tree. So far so good.

Now I want to remove the typing indicator after a while by dispatching an local action DELETE_TYPING_INDICATOR. This message will not be sent the the server or anything, it's just local. How can I do that?

I cannot dispatch an action from the reducer, as soon as the action arrives, because it is not in the reducer's responsibility right?

I cannot use a thunk in the action creator because I didn't create the action, it was a push notification from the server.

Comment: Well technically you do create the action, or at least you author where the action gets called. You must have a socket listener on the client somewhere. In that same handler you can set a timeout which will dispatch another action. This can be in a thunk or in a callback listener created in `componentDidMount`

Comment: Why would you want to manually dispatch the action `DELETE_TYPING_INDICATOR`? If the original action was from the server, you should wait for the client to receive another indicator which tells your application to dispatch `DELETE_TYPING_INDICATOR`.

Comment: @Mihir: This is just to save some messages that need to be send over the network.

Comment: @thalador I think it's wrong to manually remove the typing indicator, don't you? The typing indicator should remain there as long as the user is typing. If there is any network error, you can then manually dispatch `DELETE_TYPING_INDICATOR`.

Comment: @Mihir I am not so sure. If the typing client disconnects without sending the DELETE_TYPING_INDICATOR the the other clients will never know and it will forever show 'client is typing'. I could of course store this information on the server and add a timeout there, but it feels like overkill.

Comment: Does your server get any notification if a particular client goes offline? If it does, your server can send message to other clients that the client has gone offline. Subsequently the other clients will dispatch `DELETE_TYPING_INDICATOR` to their respective stores. It's not an overkill. It's a basic functionality in any chat application :)